# what is better way to return Set got from hibernate to client?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have 3 tables. `post`, `tag` and `post_tag`. Because `tag` will be reused on many `post`, so it can't have a column stores `post_id`. Therefore, a third table `post_tag` would have ids pointing to both `post` and `tag`.

In my `post` entity, I have

```
@Setter
@Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
private Set<PostTag> tagSet;
```

and `post_tag` entity has

```
@Setter
@Getter
@OneToOne
private Tag tag;

@Setter
@Getter
@ManyToOne
private Post post;
```

`tag` entity has just information to the tag. Everything works pretty well except I don't know how to pass the `tagSet` to client. I tried creating a new `ArrayNode` variable to manually pass the data from `tagSet`. It works, but that means when client pass `post` object back to server, I would need to manually convert `ArrayNode` to `tagSet` then have hibernate to save for me. I have no problem doing so. Just wanted to see if there's an easier way that spring and hibernate can get rid of this mapping process. I'm using hibernate and spring boot.

Comment: 1. seems too much philosophy to Post-Tag design, is is posible very natural in JPA 2. Include wide declarations, fragments give doubts. Code is main and strict communication between programmers

Comment: this is unclear (partially because code fragments), IMO must think in terms objects, classes, not tables-strings etc

Comment: how can you reuse tag table without introducing a third table? basically tag table cannot have reference to post

Comment: Three classes, agree and understand. But rest is too much 'free form speech'. Too low code. Real programmer comunicate over code (here: full class) in one secons and everything is clear.

Comment: Many, many good ideas, but must move to thinking by objects. `PostTag` is immutable, don't need setters (I had implemented similar system). "what return to client" - why not original set?